# changing QPushButton text on click

Tags: python, pyside2

I am writing a simple GUI program and need my buttons to change text when clicked. I coded it just like in example, but it does not work.

Code from example:

```
class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.hello = ["Hallo Welt", "你好，世界", "Hei maailma",
            "Hola Mundo", "Привет мир"]
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click me!")
        self.text = QtWidgets.QLabel("Hello World")
        self.text.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.text)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.magic)


    def magic(self):
        self.text.setText(random.choice(self.hello))
```

My code:

```
class Form(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Form, self).__init__()

        # Font
        r_one = QFont("RussoOne-Regular", 40, QFont.Bold) 

        # Buttons
        self.pvz_p_score = QPushButton('0')
        self.pvz_z_score = QPushButton('0')
        self.pvt_p_score = QPushButton('0')
        self.pvt_t_score = QPushButton('0')
        self.pvp_p1_score = QPushButton('0')
        self.pvp_p2_score = QPushButton('0')

        buttons = [self.pvz_p_score, 
                   self.pvz_z_score, 
                   self.pvt_p_score, 
                   self.pvt_t_score, 
                   self.pvp_p1_score,
                   self.pvp_p2_score]

        for b in buttons:
            b.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {background-color: #8ffe09;\
                                          color: black;\
                                          border: none}')
            b.setFlat(True)
            b.setIconSize(QSize(100,100))
            b.setFont(r_one)
            b.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
            b.clicked.connect(self.left_click)
            b.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.right_click)
```

...

```
    def left_click(self):
        self.text.setText(int(self.text)+1)

    def right_click(self):
        if int(self.text) > 0: button.text.setText(int(self.text)-1)
```

However, in my case `self` corresponds to `Form`, when in example it links to the `button`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the question was kinda stupid, and I have messed up with some basic python stuff, but now it is solved. Hope it will help somebody.

The first thing, `self.text` is not a field of class `Form` because **there is no such field**, as in example. Instead, for that I wanted to do, I need to somehow pass the button object to the function and acces it like `button.text()` and `button.setText()`.

As all my buttons are stored in the list `buttons`, through which I can easily iterate, I decided to create 2 functions which return functions:

```
for b in buttons:
    # I skipped style-related code
    b.clicked.connect(self.get_left_click(b))
    b.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.get_right_click(b))
```

...

```
def get_left_click(self, button):
        def left_click(self):
            button.setText(str(int(button.text())+1))
        return left_click

def get_right_click(self, button):
    def right_click(self):
        if int(button.text()) > 0: button.setText(str(int(button.text())-1))
    return right_click
```

Also, `QPushButton.setText()` does not support integers, so I had to convert it with `str(...)`

P.S. I would appreciate a better solution

Comment: Instead of adding a partial solution that also refers to something that was not in the original question, edit your question and, as already requested, provide a [**minimal, reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (it doesn't matter if it doesn't work as expected, but it *has* to be reproducible).

Answer (score 1):

1. `self.text` refers to a QLabel widget. As such, it cannot be converted to an integer for your comparison.
2. QLabel's [`text()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#text-prop) and its method `setText()` use strings, not integers. To set the text you can either convert the number to a string, or use `setNum()`, which accepts both integer and float values (but there's no `num()` function).

```
    def left_click(self):
        self.text.setText(str(int(self.text.text()) + 1))
        # alternatively:
        # self.text.setNum(int(self.text.text()) + 1)

    def right_click(self):
        if int(self.text.text()) > 0:
            button.text.setText(str(int(self.text.text()) - 1))
            # alternatively:
            # button.text.setNum(int(self.text.text()) - 1)
```

Note that I'm assuming that a text exists and it can be converted to an integer.

Comment: The problem is not in conversion. As I understand, in class `Form`, `self` refers to it's instance, not the QPushButtton one. And it makes me wonder why it works in the example. My error is `'Form' object has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: `self` always refers to the class instance, so it's the instance of Form for your code, and the instance of MyWidget in the example (why should it refer to the button?). If the error is that (you should have specified in your question, btw), it means that you didn't create the label, you're calling those functions from somewhere else or missed something you didn't show us. As already suggested, provide a [minimal, **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).